# How to locate http handler by url

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, httphandler

I'm using DevExpress web components and ASP.NET WebForms. It exposes resources (.js and .css) via handlers (for instance, /DXR.axd?r=5_0dsD)

How can I know what dll handle this URL request and where it located?
Ok, probably it located in /bin dir of web application, but still I'm wondering how to map Url to physical dll?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some handlers are missing on my staging environment. Let's say I have 10 handlers on my workstation and only 6 on test server after deployment procedure. I've check configuration and references - it's ok. And now I'm trying to find why it so

Comment: What do you mean by missing? You don't have them in your web.config? Or DXR.axd calls report errors?

Comment: missing means that for example, on this url : /DXR.axd?r=5_0dsD located nothing, but image or javascript is expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentation article](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7540) for help regarding ASPxHttpHandlerModule registration. Note that handlers/modules must also be registered in system.webServer section if you use IIS 7+ in integrated mode. Make sure that you reference same DevExpress components version you installed in your staging environment.